# The <a> tag breaks the grid layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a problem with grid layout of my learning project. Help me please. I made a part of website, but when I want to link the image and its caption to the URL by  tagging, the whole layout breaks. Here is the code without te anchors. How to place them to maintain this look of website?

```css
body{
  margin:0px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
nav {
  position:fixed;
  background:rgb(195, 44, 82);
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  
  
}
.nav-list {
  list-style-type:none;
  display:flex;
  margin:0;
 
}
li:hover{
  background:#45567d;
}
li{
  padding:1.5rem;
  font-family:helvetica;
  font-size:1.5rem;
}
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
}
header{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  font-size:18px;
  width:100%;
  color:rgb(195, 44, 82);
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
 60deg, #383838, #404040 20%, #383838 60%);
  height:100vh;
}
header > h1{
  font-style:normal;
  color:white;
  font-size:50px;
  font-family:helvetica;
}
header > h2{
  font-weight:200;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-style:italic;
  font-size:30px;
}
#projects{
  background:#45567d;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-columns: 25vw 25vw 25vw;
  justify-content:space-around;
  padding-right:5vw;
  padding-left:5vw;
  
}
#projects-text{
  width:100%;
  font-size:2rem;
  font-family:helvetica;
  color:white;
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding-top:3rem;
  padding-bottom:2rem;
  text-align:center;
  grid-column-start:1;
  grid-column-end:4;
}
img{
 width:100%;
 height:25vw;
 object-fit:cover;
 grid-row-start:2;
 grid-row-end:3;
 
 
}
#projects>p{
  background:#303841;
  color:white;
  grid-row-start:3;
  margin-top:0;
  padding:1.5rem;
  font-size:1.3rem;
  font-family:helvetica;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li>
        <a href="about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="work">Work</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <header id="welcome-section">
    <h1 id="hi">Hey I am XXXXX</h1>
    <h2>a web developer</h2>
  </header>
  <section id="projects">
    <h1 id="projects-text">These are some of my projects</h1>
     <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/tribute.jpg" alt="1" >
    <p>Tribute Page</p>
     <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/map.jpg" alt="2">
         
    <p>Map Data Across the Globe</p>
    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/wiki.png" alt="3">
    <p>Wikipedia Viewer</p>
     
   
  </section>
  
  
  
</body>
```

I would be grateful for answers.

@EDIT
Ok, here is my code in broken version. I probably need to rewrite the whole code, but I need to know why. Why this  tag is breaking code ? I thought it is some marginal thing that I can add at the end of my work :/.

```css
body{
  margin:0px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
nav {
  position:fixed;
  background:rgb(195, 44, 82);
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  
  
}
.nav-list {
  list-style-type:none;
  display:flex;
  margin:0;
 
}
li:hover{
  background:#45567d;
}
li{
  padding:1.5rem;
  font-family:helvetica;
  font-size:1.5rem;
}
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
}
header{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  font-size:18px;
  width:100%;
  color:rgb(195, 44, 82);
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
 60deg, #383838, #404040 20%, #383838 60%);
  height:100vh;
}
header > h1{
  font-style:normal;
  color:white;
  font-size:50px;
  font-family:helvetica;
}
header > h2{
  font-weight:200;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-style:italic;
  font-size:30px;
}
.projects{
  background:#45567d;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-columns: 25vw 25vw 25vw;
  justify-content:space-around;
  padding-right:5vw;
  padding-left:5vw;
  
}
#projects-text{
  width:100%;
  font-size:2rem;
  font-family:helvetica;
  color:white;
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding-top:3rem;
  padding-bottom:2rem;
  text-align:center;
  grid-column-start:1;
  grid-column-end:4;
}
img{
 width:100%;
 height:25vw;
 object-fit:cover;
 grid-row-start:2;
 grid-row-end:3;
 
 
}
#projects>p{
  background:#303841;
  color:white;
  grid-row-start:3;
  margin-top:0;
  padding: ;
  font-size:1.3em;
  font-family:helvetica;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li>
        <a href="about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="work">Work</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <header id="welcome-section">
    <h1 id="hi">Hey I am XXXXX</h1>
    <h2>a web developer</h2>
  </header>
  <section class="projects">
    <h1>These are some of my projects</h1>
    
    <a 
      href="https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/zNqgVx"
      target="_blank"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/tribute.jpg" alt="1" >
  <p>Tribute Page</p>
    </a>
     <a 
      href="https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/zNqgVx"
      target="_blank">
       <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/map.jpg" alt="2">
       <p>Map Data Across the Globe</p>
    </a>
    <a 
      href="https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/zNqgVx"
      target="_blank">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/wiki.png" alt="3">
      <p>Wikipedia Viewer</p>
    </a>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: So do I understand correctly, you want images to be links?

Comment: Provide code that is "broken" so we can understand what are You doing wrong

Comment: Use the CSS settings which you applied to the images (width/height, grid paramters)  to those `a` tags instead (use a class to not apply it to any other a tags), and apply only `object-fit:cover;` to the images to  "fill" those `a` tags

Comment: Elman Huseynov I want the image and the paragraph under the image to be a link.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap each of your images in an anchor tag like this

```
<a href="your url">
  <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/tribute.jpg" alt="1" >
</a>
```